# One result from 2 rows same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have the following table

```
ID | Person | Type | Function
-----------------------------
1  | John   | 1    | 1
2  | Smith  | 1    | 2
```

I want do a query to get a single result from both rows. The first column is `Person as ProjectLead where function = 1 and type = 1` and the second column is `Person as Stakeholder where function = 2 and type = 1`

```
ProjectLead | Stakeholder
-----------------------------
John        | Smith
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: This is classic pivot

Comment: What is the SQL Server version?

Comment: @lad2025: it's not even pivot, just a self-join.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a self join on the `type`:

```
SELECT projectlead, stakeholder
FROM   (SELECT person AS projectlead, type
        FROM   mytable
        WHERE  function = 1) p
JOIN   (SELECT person AS stakeholder, type
        FROM   mytable
        WHERE  function = 2) s ON p.type = s.type
```

Answer (score 0):

SelfJoin on your table

```
SELECT  ProjectLead = ProjectLead.Person,
        Stakeholder = StakeHolder.Person
FROM [YourTableName] AS ProjectLead
LEFT JOIN [YourTableName] AS StakeHolder ON StakeHolder [Function] = 2 AND StakeHolder.[TYPE] = 1
WHERE ProjectLead.[Function] = 1 AND ProjectLead.[TYPE] = 1
```